# Calendar Invitations do not Work

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos, calendar

Unfortunately, I have a problem with the use of Apple Calendar: When I invite someone to an event (iCloud Calendar), they do not receive a notification and cannot agree to the event.
However, when someone else invites me, I directly receive a push notification that allows me to join the event.

I also have a similar problem in the Photos app. When I create a shared album and invite people, they do not receive an invitation and cannot join the album. However, if someone else creates the album and invites me, I see that invitation and everything works.

These issues occur on all of my iOS devices iPhone XR, iPad & MacBook Pro (with current software).

Ultimately, outgoing invitations of any kind do not arrive, while incoming invitations work fine. Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do the people you invite have an apple id? Are they also zsing calendar? Do the people who invite you have an apple id and calendar?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes they have both. When they invite me it is also working.